# Not able to establish socket connection in Android using ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, sockets, socket.io, ionic4

Not able to establish socket connection in Android device using ionic-4

I am able to establish the connection via browser and ios devices but strangely not able to on android devices.

**app.module.ts**

```
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://www.example.com:3434',
                                options: {} };

 @NgModule({
   declarations: [AppComponent],
   entryComponents: [],
   imports: [
               BrowserModule, 
               IonicModule.forRoot(), 
               AppRoutingModule,
               SocketIoModule.forRoot(config),
               IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
               CommonModule,
               ComponentModule,
             ],
   providers: [
                  StatusBar,
                  SplashScreen,
                  { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: 
                  IonicRouteStrategy },
                  Network
              ],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**socket-connection.service.ts**

```
   import { Socket }  from 'ngx-socket-io';
   import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

   export class SocketConnectionService {

       constructor(public socket : Socket) { }

       request(){
           this.socket.emit('request',data)
       }

   }
```

Comment: please provide errors, too little information to help

Comment: not getting any error. Just not able to connect.

Comment: The issue is only with android version 8.0, in the previous versions it is working as expected.

Comment: I don't think I have had any issue with connection and I am using the `ngx-socket-io` package as well. So you are saying that when you try to connect your server instance of socket.io is not registering a connection?

Comment: @Ctfrancia, yes socket.io is not registering a connection at all. When I downgraded the android version in Cordova it worked as expected without any change to the code.